# Why cant windows xp installer, either 32 or 64 but, detect my IDE drives. No SATA

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, setup

Windows XP installers can't find hard drive to install to. The available drives are both IDE. All answers I've found just ignore this when mentioned in the question, and instead focus on SATA driver issues, which do not apply here. The drives are correctly seen in BIOS. The target drive is NTFS formatted with a clean partition ready for XP. The motherboard is ASUS P5LD2 with 4 GB, and I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks SQR

Comment: There are two ATA controllers apparently. One of them is a builtin one in the south bridge, one being a standalone chip. Things may be easier if you make sure the drive is using the port wired to the south bridge one, which is the one that is closer to the RAM slots. (Although I won't rule out that you will need to side load drivers anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

The ASUS P5LD2 motherboard has an old RAID feature that does require drivers (for Windows XP) indeed: https://www.asus.com/br/supportonly/p5ld2/helpdesk_download/

Those drivers AREN'T required for Windows Vista 64-bit, the Windows version your motherboard was designed for.

You can't install Windows XP in RAID mode unless you *slipstream* the "IT8211 ATA RAID Controller Driver and Application V1.3.2.8 for Windows 2000 & XP/2003" into the installation media.

You can and probably should install without the RAID. Just make sure the drive mode is "Native IDE" or similar. Check your user's manual.

Answer (score -1):

The issue still comes back to drivers.  Windows XP has a limited number of IDE drivers built-in.  It would appear Windows XP doesn't have the drivers for your IDE controller chip.

You need to download and uncompress the driver files until you see the INF file.

If I remember correctly XP has an option to press F7 and insert a floppy disk containing the drivers you just downloaded.

Software does exist to directly inject drivers into the windows ISO, but I don't remember what I used back in the XP days.

https://www.asus.com/supportonly/p5ld2/helpdesk_download/

You will obviously need the RAID IDE controller drivers.  I would also download both chipset drivers, the regular one and the one listed as "Other" in case you need them also.